# Obter diretório Documents com python automaticamente

Tags: python

Preciso obter automaticamente o endereço da pasta de documentos de qualquer Windows com Python.

Atualmente em meu *script* determinei como mostrado na variável `main_folder`, porém sempre que mudo de PC tenho que alterar esse endereço. Segue abaixo também um dos usos desta variável em meu *script*.

Criação de diretórios e sub diretórios. Caso alguém conheça mais algum método, serei muito grato.

```
import arcpy
main_folder = r"C:\Users\Edeson Bizerril\Documents\myEBpy_Files"

# EXEMPLO DE USO
# Determinando diretório
input_folder = main_folder + "\Input\\"
input_folder_SRTM = self.input_folder + r"SRTMs\\"

create_folder(input_folder)

create_folder(input_folder_SRTM)

# Método para criação de diretórios
def create_folder(path):
    if not os.path.isdir(path):
        os.makedirs(path)
```

Infelizmente preciso determinar a pasta de referência em meu trabalho, mas gostaria que o Python identificasse automaticamente e me retornasse exatamente o mesmo resultado na variável `main_folder`.

Comment: Cara, não consegui entender direito o que você quer. Tem como colocar um exemplo de output ou mesmo um passo a passo com início, meio e fim?

Comment: Eu trabalho com ArcGis e python, dai eu preciso informar ao arcgis o endereço principal de trabalho. Da forma como foi informado dá certo, porque eu informo a ele associando essa variável. Mas sempre que eu mudo de pc eu preciso alterar o nome de usuário. entende? Mas eu vou ver se consigo melhorar essa pergunta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na biblioteca padrão do python existe o módulo `os.path` que possui vários métodos para auxiliar na manipulação dos diretórios do sistema operacional.

Para você obter o diretório inicial (home) do usuário você pode utilizar a função `expanduser`.

```
from os import path


main_folder = path.join(path.expanduser("~"), "Documents/myEBpy_Files")
```

No Windows retornará: `C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\myEBpy_Files`

Comment: Perfeito - eu não sabia que o expanduser funcionava no Windows também.

Acho que dá pra fazer numa chamada só, não dá? `path.expanduser("~/Documents/myEBpy_Files")` - o `~` automaticamente já vira o caminho até a pasta do usuário.

Comment: Até pensei nisso, mas no teste que realizei não houve o tratamento da "/", por isso usei o `join`.

Answer (score 1):

Com a nova API de manipulação de diretórios, `pathlib`, você pode obter o diretório do usuário a partir de:

```
from pathlib import Path
home = Path.home()
```

Isso retornará um objeto referente ao diretório *home* do usuário em questão. Para acessar o diretório "Documentos", bastará fazer:

```
documents = home / 'Documentos'
```

O operador de divisão, neste caso, é sobrecarregado para alterar o diretório, para seguir a mesma sintaxe do sistema operacional.