# Python3: Como tratar caminhos relativos com modulo os

Tags: python-3.x

Tenho o metodo abaixo:

```
def get_conteudo_file(filename: str, encoding: str="iso8859-1") -> str:
    filename = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(*filename.split(os.sep)))
    assert os.path.isfile(filename), "Arquivo '{}' indisponível".format(filename)
    with open(filename, encoding=encoding) as f:
        logging.debug('filename: "{}" readed'.format(f.name))
        return f.read()

get_conteudo_file("~/Documents/projeto/me.py", "utf-8")
```

Como tratar este caminho relativo para acessar o arquivo?

Comment: Qual foi o problema? Ele não localizou o arquivo? Qual foi o valor final de `filename`?

Comment: Foi algo do tipo "/home/brito/projetos/este_projeto/me/~/Documents/projeto/me.py"

Comment: Veja se essa resposta te ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/335516/5878